# OneDrive Graph API Root directory returns SharePoint shared documents instead of OneDrive

Tags: api, onedrive

I am running the OneDrive API Browser demo application and am not able to get it to load up my OneDrive for Business files.  Instead, it will return the root URL as the company SharePoint site on 365.  If I use my personal Microsoft account, it will properly load the OneDrive URL for that one, but not the company account.  Not sure how to get around this.

Also, I did not know what forum category to choose, since none of the options were for OneDrive (let alone OneDrive API), so I chose the closest match I could find.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and signing in?
The OneDrive examples here always list my OneDrive items.
Cheers
Steve

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was not aware this existed. I’ll have to try that when I get back in town.

Comment: That helped me solve the issue.  Apparently Microsoft kept out a key word in the URL ("/me/") when they created this demo application. For anyone with a similar issue, if you are using GraphServiceClient.Drive.Root to create the URL path, you will need to change it to GraphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root to get the proper URL to your OneDrive documents, instead of SharePoint documents. The original path would return as "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/", but it needs to be "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/".